# Using xidel to extract a key-value pair

Tags: html, xpath, xidel

I have multiple tables on a website like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Count</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>2014-11-17</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Count</td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>2014-12-24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
...
```

I want to receive something like this

```
foo    15
bar    42
```

My first attempt in xidel was `xidel --xpath "//table/tr[1]/td[2]" --xpath "//table/tr[2]/td[2]"` but this is giving

```
foo
bar

15
42
```

How can I extract two values in one line?

Answer (score 2):

Using XPath or XQuery 3.0: `//table/tbody/(tr[1]/td[2] || ' ' || tr[2]/td[2])`. I think you need to request that version explicitly, at least I needed to do so on http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi. And I parsed as HTML where the parser adds a tbody element and the path needs that too.

Answer (score 1):

```
xidel-0.9.5.4998.exe -s --input-format=xml <input> ^
                     --xquery "//table/concat(tr[1]/td[2],'&#09;',tr[2]/td[2])"
foo     15
bar     42
```

Comment: This looks like a command, but it isn't wrapped properly and it lacks a description of what you're doing and how it works.